# dropdown menu with different mail address

Tags: php, jquery, email, menu

i'm building this site and i need to create this dropdown menu with different mail address to different departments, this is what i have so far

```
<div class="col-lg-5 formulario text-right" id="formContacto">
  <h3 class="text-left">atención al consumidor</h3>
    <form id="contacto">
      <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre completo" />
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
      <textarea id="consulta" placeholder="¿Cuál es su consulta?"></textarea>
      <select id="turno" class="form-control-footer">
        <option value="-">Campo</option>
        <option value="mail@address.com">Turismo    </option>
        <option value="mail@address.com">Ventas</option>
        <option value="mail@address.com">Marketing</option>
        <option value="mail@address.com">RRHH</option>
      </select>
    <br>
    <div id="txt_msj"></div>
    <br>
    <a id="btnEnviar" class="btn btn-info text-right">ENVIAR <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></a>
    </form>
</div>
```

what i don't know is how to make it so when you click the send button it send the mail to it's appropriate address

Comment: small recommendation, don't expose the email addresses in your html this way, use an index number that corresponds to an array or database on your backend.

Comment: please, explain it to me like i was a 5 year old child

Comment: Give your select a name attribute then use POST array. Your method should also be POST. Forms default to GET if not included. `isset()` - `empty()` should also be used.

Comment: where is your form action script? you need to post it to the script.

Comment: There, you have an "answer" below. Have a chat with them.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your form fields will need a name attribute so they can be accessed as $_post['name']

The form should also be set to have a method of post

finally you will use the email variable in your mail function once cleaned and verified.

Comment: *Um....*, I believe that's already been established in comments. You got some code for the OP to go with this? Plus, `$_post` will outright fail. Look up superglobals on PHP.net